# Problem with default 3rd person controller in Unity 4

Tags: unity

I am new to Unity. Whenever I am importing the default 3rd person controller (construction worker) in my scene and clicking the play button, the model seems to be in the running pose.

The control keys are working properly, and I am also being able to make the character stand, walk, run and jump properly.
Only problem is that it is always in the running pose - which looks very odd.
I did not make any change to anything. I just imported the controller as is.

Can someone please tell me how to correct this issue?

P.S. I hope my question was clear.

Comment: btw in my book I develop a new 3rd person controller from the ground up, so that readers can see exactly how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the 3rd person controller is set to auto-play the "run" animation by default. At least in my case, and I'm guessing in yours too, since I did not change the controller in any way.
To fix the issue, select the third person controller and go to its Animation component in the Inspector View (the panel to the right). It should look like this:

[image]

Next, click on "Animation", just like the picture says, and select "idle". The controller will stay idle by default now, and not run aimlessly on the spot.

LE: One more thing. It seems some users have another issue with the 3rd person controller. Apparently in Unity 4 its animation clips are not set up by default. If you see this:
[image]

Then you need to click on each MISSING animation clip and set it manually. Idle Animation should be "idle", and so forth. When selecting animations, take a look at each one's path (at the bottom of the selection window), and make sure they're coming from the 3rd person controller only!

Good luck!